# Disabling Auto/Dwell Click doesn't work in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mouse

I have unchecked all the dwell click options in gconf (configuration editor) but still auto click is enabled, teasing me. In Ubuntu 12.04, mouse setting option under 'All Settings' doesn't provide any option to cause auto click disabled. How to get out of here?

Answer (score 3):

Go to: System Settings > Universal Access.  Select Tab: Pointing and Clicking.  Turn Off: Hover Click

Answer (score 2):

One way I came across in the ubuntuforums was...`mousetweaks -s`. It worked for me, try it!

From the terminal do `sudo apt-get install mousetweaks` to install mousetweaks or use the software center.