# Mouse and the Hoverclick

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse, touchpad

I´ve got a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Thinkpad T530.
The mouse (and the touchpad, too) makes automatic hoverclicks (prime button) after 3 second of no move. 
Settings Manager-> Onboard Settings -> Universal Access is still deactivated.
I need help, cause it´s hard to work with this "bug" or is it a "feature" ???

Comment: Never seen such a behavior --- unless the mouse is busted. Did it happen with the touchpad even if you disconnect the mouse?

Comment: Did you check out these links http://askubuntu.com/questions/192095/disabling-auto-dwell-click-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-12-04 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/38254/how-to-disable-on-mouse-stop-auto-click

Comment: It happens on both ways. With and without USB mouse.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192095/disabling-auto-dwell-click-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-12-04 don´t work.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38254/how-to-disable-on-mouse-stop-auto-click ... Universal Access is still deactivated!